# Ionic Decrease Scroll Speed

Tags: ionic-framework

i got problem when trying to slowing scroll from this code :

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('credit').scrollBottom(true).
```

How can i slowing down the scroll? Because now it scrolling too fast for me. I need to slowing down the scroll, just like credit scene on the Star Wars movie.

Anyhelp would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
$scope.viewCreditsV2 = function () {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('views/popupcredit.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
            $scope.modal.show();
            if ($scope.modal.isShown()){                               
                setTimeout(function() {
                      // Do something after 2 seconds
                     $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('credit').scrollBottom(true);
                }, 2000);
            }
        });

    $scope.openModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };
    $scope.closeModal = function() {
        // $scope.modal.hide();
        $scope.modal.remove();
    };
};
```

Comment: can you show me more code?

Answer (score 11):

This question is old but somebody might use it.

Even though there are no parameters to pass options, you can still access the ScrollView object using the `$ionScrollDelegate`.

Following @Jeremy Wilken's answer (which helped me derive this one), you could do:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().options.animationDuration = 400;
    console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().options);
});


//.....

$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBy(0,20, true) // Animation will be slower now
```

I wrapped the call on a `$timeout` to avoid racing conditions from `$ionicScrollDelegate` not being created.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic doesn't have a means to change the animation speed for the $ionicScrollDelegate. There is no public API to make this change.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/views/scrollView.js#L327

You can use `$anchorScroll` as shown in the Angular documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: thanks but still i need animation for that, maybe i should use css animation