# How to make ionic content to move faster on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I've developed an app in ionic framework.But when i scroll i see a lag on page.How can i make the app to move faster on scrolling?Thanks!

Comment: Please see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742525/ionic-decrease-scroll-speed you might  get some Idea about How to do it ??

Comment: Which platform are you using? Is the content store large amount of text?